# writing a presenter for index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, presenter

I would like to make a presenter for the `Event` index view, which currently iterates through all events like this:

```
<% @events each do |event| %>
  <td><%= link_to event.name, event_path(event) %></td>
<% end %>
```

there will be many other things in there, but this is the gist of it. I want to be able to do something like:

```
<% present @events do |event_presenter| %>
  <td><%= event_presenter.event_title %></td>
<% end %>
```

the `EventPresenter` would be subclass of the `BasePresenter`, taken from [Railscast 287](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch)

```
class BasePresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

private

  def self.presents(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end

  def h
    @template
  end

  def markdown(text)
    Redcarpet.new(text, :hard_wrap, :filter_html, :autolink).to_html.html_safe
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @template.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

What confuses me is that in the Railscast the example is for show action, not index action. There are no iterations in the view like `@events each do |event|` . You can't just stick the method into the presenter file this way:

```
  def event_title
    link_to event.name, event_path(event)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally manage this thing more manually, i find it easier to handle that way and reason about exactly what is going on when i need to change something or debug.

Anyway, the way that i do that is normally in the controller.

```
def index
  @events = Event.all.map(|event| EventPresenter.new(event))
end
```

Then in your views they are already mapped over to what you are needing.